# Dev c++ Editor closes on project loads

Tags: wxwidgets, dev-c++

When i load existing project in dev c++. After some files loading. Dev C++ gets closed automatically. I am not sure what is the reason. I am new to this environment. so its difficult for me to fix or trouble shoot this issue. Can any one help for me to troubleshoot?

Environment:

OS:windows xp;
Dev C++ : 4.9.9.2
Installed wxwidgets2.9.3

Comment: Why are you using dev-C++?  Have you read the description on the tag?http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dev-c%2b%2b/info

Comment: Since you are using windows, may I suggest VS2010 Express, instead of Dev-C++. If not VS2010, go for Codeblocks, or codelite. All three of them work great with wxWidgets.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider either upgrading to http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/?source=directory, and trying again, or migrating to any other C/C++ IDE.

If this problem is stil present in the new version, mail be with a bug report (I'm the current developer), or read through the longer devc++ tag description for alternatives.

Also, you might want to have a look at wxDev-C++, which is purpose made to support wx.